# How consult a table with repeated reference value and different status

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a table that has two entries for the same hostname with two different status, example:

- Host_X appears with the status `PRODUCTION` and `POSTPRODUCTION`

However my query must have the following logic:

1. Search for all hostnames regardless of status
2. Select only hostnames that have only 1 entry as `POSTPRODUCTION`

I tried something like:

```
AND (STATUS = 'POSTPRODUCTION' AND STATUS <> 'PRODUCTION')
```

But there was no success in the result, below is an example of consultation in this table:

```
SELECT
    HOSTNAME
FROM
    CI
WHERE
    STATUS = 'PRODUCTION'
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Those two conditions are mutually incompatible.

Comment: That's the big problem, they screwed up my life

Comment: I'm trying to solve this with some kind of `CASE WHEN` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a window function to count the number of rows per host:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by HOSTNAME) as cnt
      from ci t
     ) t;
```

The second condition is then:

```
where cnt = 1 and status = 'POSTPRODUCTION'
```